# how to call the function in the specs - Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I write this script under the module:

```js
   var enter_search = function () {

this.clickSearch = function (value) {
    element(by.id('searchbutton')).click();
};


this.waitElementFound = function (value) {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.presenceof(value), 35000);
};

};
module.exports = new enter_search();
```

and to call this function on my spec, i wrote this:

```js
var search =  require('enter_search');
var loadtxt = element (by.id('text'));

it('waits for the element', function(){
  search.waitElementFound(loadtxt);
  search.clickSearch();
});
```

When I execute the test, it gives me an error undefined function. Not sure what went wrong. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are giving proper path to the javascript file that you are importing? Have exported your javascript file module? Thanks

Comment: yes, because I also called another function from the same javascript file and it kept passing. So I am wondering if there maybe something wrong with how i call it, or how I may have declare my variable in the function itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this, i just had to declare my variables outside the var x = function.. struggles of a newbie :) thanks anyway @Girish Sotur

Answer (score 1):

To use functions from one file in another, you should [export](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) the function and then require it in the other file. Here's an example -

File **test.js**

```
var search =  require('./helper.js');
var loadtxt = element(by.id('text'));

it('waits for the element', function(){
    search.waitElementFound(loadtxt);
});
```

File **helper.js**

```
var waitElementFound = function (value) {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(value), 35000);
};

module.exports = new waitElementFound(); //export the function
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Marj can you add necessary code in the question so that we can debug it better? Thanks

Comment: @Marj just to confirm, your `clickSearch()` function is working or its failing too? Thanks

Comment: clickSearch is working perfectly, it is only this waitElementFound that is having issues :(

Comment: @Marj, are you importing your module with proper file - `var search =  require('enter_search');`. You should actually be giving complete path to the `enter_search.js` file. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Girish, yes I did that already. clickSearch is inside that enter_search.js file.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   var enter_search = function () {

this.clickSearch = function (value) {
    element(by.id('searchbutton')).click();
};


this.waitElementFound = function (value) {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.presenceof(value), 35000);
};

};
module.exports = new enter_search();
```

Comment: Can you explain where the asker made the mistake? (Posting only code is often not very helpful)